# How to pass a list of object from view to controller in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller :-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertAddress(EmployeeViewModel model)
    {
           //code for insert data into db
    }
```

View :- 
[image]

Here i want to call InsertAddress action by passing multiple address objects along with single employee object from view to controller .

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the correct naming conventions for the model binder to understand.

Property.Property

Or

Property[index].Property for Collections

If index isn't sequential 0 based you need to add a hidden field, Property.Index with the value of the index

Example:

```
<input name="Employee.Name" value="1234 5678"/>
<input name="Employee.Phone value="1234 5678"/>
<input name="Employee.Email" value="me@example.com"/>
<input name="Addresses.Index" value="0" type="hidden"/>
<input name="Addresses[0].Suburb" value="Melbourne"/>
<input name="Addresses[0].Postcode" value="3000"/>
<input name="Addresses.Index" value="1" type="hidden"/>
<input name="Addresses[1].Suburb" value="Sydney"/>
<input name="Addresses[1].Postcode" value="2000"/>
```

When your inserting a row, just use the naming convention, and don't forget to add the .Index field.

Most the default EditorFor will handle all of this for you transparently if you create a custom EditorTemplate for your Address class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it possible, but requires a little work on your part.

Rather than having a single view for the model (with some sort of loop for the addresses), you need to create an EditorTemplate for your Address class, and then in the main view use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Addresses)`

This setup will cause your `EmployeeViewModel` instance to be returned to your action containing the full list of Addresses (rather than it being empty).

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned some common issues while binding complex models, have a look here
http://jayakarant.blogspot.de/2014/05/handling-complex-view-models-in-razor.html